# Python3 Twisted Mysql Error

Tags: python, twisted

So today I have decided to start a new project (long story).
And in this project I need MySQL connections.
I am currently using python 3.6 and want to use twisted so I have imported the module by doing the following:

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
```

The only problem is, since I am using python3 I can't use MySQLdb right so I need mysqlclient, thing is how can I use it as a MySQL DB module ? Because this connection line here:

```
self.Connection = adbapi.ConnectionPool("mysqlclient", db = Config['Database'], port = 3306, user=Config['User'], passwd = Config['Password'], host = Config['Host'])
```

give me this following error:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysqlclient'`

If anyone could help I'd be thankful.
Have a great day/night.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install whichever MySQL client library you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 'MySQLdb' instead of 'mysqlclient'.
like this:

```
self.Connection = adbapi.ConnectionPool("MySQLdb", db = Config['Database'], port = 3306, user=Config['User'], passwd = Config['Password'], host = Config['Host'])
```